# sssd windows domain users does not have privileges over the ubuntu gui

Tags: windows, gui, sssd

ive currently installed a fresh ubuntu 16.04 and joined it to the domain using SSSD and realmd following this walk through:
http://www.wolffhaven45.com/active-directory/join_ubuntu_workstation_windows_domain/
and it worked, now i can access the Ubuntu machine with my windows domain user and after adding the user to the sudoers group i can do everything on terminal, but GUI doesn't work with me, cannot change settings and cannot manage users and cannot install any software form Ubuntu software

how to give SSSD windows domain users privilage on the ubuntu 16.04 GUI (unity)

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by adding the sudo group I'd created in AD to the /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/51-ubuntu-admin.conf config file.

In my case the AD group to allow sudo in the terminal was EngineeringSudo, so my 51-ubuntu-admin.conf file looks like this now.

```
[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-group:sudo;unix-group:admin;unix-group:EngineeringSudo
```

This works by making your AD sudo group an "Administrator" as far as PolKit is concerned.